# Setting a "tag" with Flurry Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, flurry

I am working on an iOS app, and using Flurry Analytics to track analytics. In the app, the user has the option of selecting a group to belong to. Is there a way to mark analytics with a tag, so that I can separate the analytics for each group in Flurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Segments feature in Flurry to track user groups based on age, gender, location, custom events, date range, etc. In your particular case, you can log an event when a user makes a selection, and assign that event to a unique Segment. The analytics of each Segment can be tracked independently on the developer dashboard. Please write to support@flurry.com if you need any further assistance on this. (Disclaimer: I work at Flurry)

Comment: Note that you are only allowed 10 segments per application.